# What are some reliable ways, to detect an Activity restore from home press?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

After user press HOME button, I would like to display a password protection screen when user

1. Restore the Activity from recent list. Or,
2. Press the app icon, and restore the last "minimize" Activity.

But not during

3. When user launches the Activity.
4. When user rotates device, and the Activity went through configuration change.
5. When user launches "other Activity", and then close the "other Activity".

All the above 5 actions, will trigger Activity's `onResume`

But, I would like to display a password protection screen **only** for the first 2 actions, and avoid from doing anything in the last 3 actions.

May I know, how can I achieve so? Will `LifecycleObserver` able to assist me on this?

---

### What I had tried on `LifecycleObserver`

```
public class NewGenericFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static class MyLifeCycleObserver implements DefaultLifecycleObserver {
        @Override
        public void onResume(LifecycleOwner owner) {
            Log.i("CHEOK", "onResume(LifecycleOwner owner)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause(LifecycleOwner owner) {
            Log.i("CHEOK", "onPause(LifecycleOwner owner)");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getLifecycle().addObserver(new MyLifeCycleObserver());
```

For `MyLifeCycleObserver`'s `onResume` and `onPause`, it will be trigger for Actions 1 to 5. It is not clear, how I can separate Action 1, 2 from 3, 4, 5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `LifecycleObserver` [can do this](https://proandroiddev.com/detecting-when-an-android-app-backgrounds-in-2018-4b5a94977d5c).
After adding the proper imports to your build.gradle file, create the following file in your project:

```
class SampleLifecycleListener : LifecycleObserver {

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
fun onMoveToForeground() {
    Log.d("SampleLifecycle", "Returning to foreground…")
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
fun onMoveToBackground() {
    Log.d("SampleLifecycle", "Moving to background…")
}
}
```

and in your app's custom Application class, add this line to `onCreate()`:

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(SampleLifecycleListener())
```

Comment: Sorry. I can get what you mean. But, since the events is received in Application level, how can I convey the information back to the target Activity?